# How to make AddWebAllowedObject() function works in UWP project?

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10-universal

I want to make a demo to call native method in js in a WebView, but failed.

Below is C# code:

```
namespace webviewDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        [AllowForWeb]
        public sealed class MyNativeClass
        {
            public void NativeMethod()
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(".................MyNativeClass::NativeMethod() is invoked!");
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MyWebView.NavigationStarting += MyWebView_NavigationStarting;

            Uri navigationUri = new Uri(@"http://10.119.116.160/test/tom/test.html");
            Debug.WriteLine("......................navigate the url");
            MyWebView.Navigate(navigationUri);
        }

        private void MyWebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(".................MyWebView_NavigationStarting() is executing");
            MyWebView.AddWebAllowedObject("nativeObject", new MyNativeClass());
        }
    }
}
```

Below is test.html source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        nativeObject.NativeMethod(); // Call the projected WinRT method.
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

When the app starts to run, the output log is below:

```
......................navigate the url
.................MyWebView_NavigationStarting() is executing
```

Package.appxmanifest:

```
  <uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
    <uap:Rule Type="include" Match="http://10.119.116.160/test/tom/test.html" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all"/>
  </uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
```

As you can see, the NativeMethod() function log is not printed, means it is not called at all.
How to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work "nativeObject" needs to be a Windows Runtime Component. In your code example it is just a plain C# class.

The easiest way to implement a C# WinRT Component is by adding a new project to your  solution of type "C# - Windows Runtime Component", and add a reference from your app project to this. Then implement your C# code as usual in the new project.

[image]